# GitHub Actions deploy multiple functions

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions

as per this doc - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions

working when I run firebase deploy from local CLI

`package.json`

```json
"deploy:prod": "firebase deploy --only functions:fun1, functions:fun2"
```

not working when I execute this through GitHub Actions.

below code works and deploys fun1 because only one function im deploying
`package.json`

```json
"deploy:prod": "firebase deploy --only functions:fun1"
```

any idea how to deploy multiple functions using GitHub Actions?

YML file

name: Deploy PROD
on:
workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
build_and_deploy_functions_prod:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Install npm packages
run: |
cd functions
npm ci
npm install firebase-tools
- name: Deploy to Firebase
run: cd functions && npm run deploy:prod
env:
FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}

---

package.json
"scripts": {
"deploy:prod": "firebase use prod && firebase deploy --only functions:fun1, functions:fun2"
},

Comment: Please show your YAML and logs

Comment: YML

name: Deploy  PROD
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_functions_prod
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install npm packages
        run: |
          cd functions 
          npm ci
          npm install firebase-tools
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        run: cd functions && npm run deploy:prod
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}

Comment: Package.json

"deploy:prod": "npm run clean && firebase use prod && firebase deploy --only functions:fun1, functions:fun2"

Comment: updated with yml file and package.json

Comment: Error: Process completed with exit code 1.